# Execute code in a class library when you do not have a reference to that class library

Tags: c#

Say I have a class library like this:

```
  using ClassLibrary2;

        namespace ClassLibrary1
    {
        public class Class1 : IClass1
        {
            public string SayHello()
            {
                return "Hello";
            }
        }  
    }
```

and a class library like this:

```
 namespace ClassLibrary2
    {
        public interface IClass1
        {
            string SayHello();
        }

        public class Class3
        {
            IClass1 _class1;

            public Class3(IClass1 class1)
            {
                _class1 = class1;
                string test = _class1.SayHello();
            }
        }
    }
```

and a program like this:

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {


           public partial class Form1 : Form
            {
                public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    IClass1 class1 = new Class1();
                    Class3 class3 = new Class3(class1);
                }
            }
        }
```

ClassLibrary1 references ClassLibrary2.   WindowsFormsApplication1 references ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2.

The program finishes.  ClassLibrary2 is able to execute code from ClassLibrary1 even though ClassLibrary2 does not reference ClassLibrary1.  What is this technique called? I want to read more about it and use it.  I realise it is polymorphism.  I am referring to the technique of executing code in a class library without a dependancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You discovered the D in [`SOLID`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)): Dependency inversion principle.

Program against interfaces, not implementations.

You are *not* executing code from ClassLibrary1 in ClassLibrary2, you are invoking functionality described in an interface that you defined in ClassLibrary2 itself.
At runtime, the implementation of what you invoke may be provided by ClassLibrary12635.

One example where this can be really useful is if I define an interface for, say, a DAL (Data access layer) component in a separate library, defining the functionality of that DAL component. I can implement business logic in a business logic layer (BLL) using that interface (I need to reference the library with the interface).

For my DAL itself I can implement different implementations, and create two different libraries - for instance one that uses local, client side storage, and another that uses a centralised database. I can then substitute one DAL library for the other without having to change a single line of code in my business logic.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess dependancy inversion is good practice.  What is classlibrary12635? +1 for SOLID reference.

Comment: `classlibrary12635` is just another classlibrary that could exist, or that you could write, or that may appear, that just happens to also implement the `IClass1` interface. The whole point is that ClassLibrary3 should not care at all whether it is ClassLibrary1, classlibrary12635, or `somethirdpartylibrary` that implements IClass1, as long as it works.