# Visual Studio Multi Project Solution Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have this solution in VS 2017 which has multiple projects:

- Example.DomainModels
- Example.DataAccess
- Example.Infrastructure
- Example.Web

So well, my `Web` project references `Infrastructure` and the `Infrastructure` project references `DataAccess` as well as `DomainModels` projects. The solution is working fine.

However, if inside my `Web` project, if I try to access any of the entities from the `DomainModels`, I can easily access that without any errors, even though `Web` project doesn't have any reference to the `DomainModels`.

Can you please help me understand how this referencing of the project works? Is it because the web project has indirect reference to the DomainModels (`Web` -> `Infrastructure` -> `DomainModels`)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please investigate the Onion architecture: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36655.onion-architecture-in-asp-net-core-mvc.aspx

The Domain Model should not reference anything.  In order to achieve this; you should investigate dependancy inversion.  I asked a question recently about dependancy inversion here: [Execute code in a class library when you do not have a reference to that class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650808/execute-code-in-a-class-library-when-you-do-not-have-a-reference-to-that-class-l)

If you want to divorce the domain layer from the web then you could introduce a service layer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand that. I am just trying to get my head around referencing thing here. So my question mainly here was concerned with the references and not architectures and patterns. DomainModels isn't referencing anything anyway.

Comment: See my last paragraph about how to divorce the web layer from the domain layer.

Comment: O right right. I got it. The question you asked helped me understand the concept. Right so this means DI should be used to restrict access.

Comment: Yes.  I would also include a service layer

Answer (score 1):

Indeed , as per your comments web will have reference to all other projects

When you compile , The Infrastructure will be having references dataaccess and domain model namespaces attached to it hence you are able to access the types or namespaces present in dataaccess and domain models from web since you are refering Infrastructure from web .

Comment: Is there any way to restrict the access of DomainEntities from Web?

Comment: I'm not sure about that but you can use access modifiers , Static , Sealed , Singleton methodologies to restrict the access of your classes present in DomainEntities . Since you are referring to Infrastructure , only way is to get rid of DomainEntities from Infrastructure .